# Change folder permissions on 2008 terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, terminal-server, file-permissions

I have a Windows 2003 R2 domain controller and a 2008 SP2 terminal server. How can I give a group `MYDOMAIN\MyGroup` custom permissions for the TS's `C:\example` directory? When I try to add a user or group in `C:\example`'s security properties, the location field is not changeable from `TermServName` and `MYDOMAIN\MyGroup` is never found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the DNS settings on the 2008 SP2 term server pointing at the IP of the 2003 R2 domain controller? That's what I usually see when the domain is not listed as a location.